# How to subscribe to the event when the AutoCAD application is initialized and ready to work?

Tags: c#, interop, autocad, autocad-plugin

How to subscribe to an event using the Autodesk.Autocad.Interop library when the AutoCAD application is launched, initialized, and ready to work

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the [`Application.Idle`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-Autodesk_AutoCAD_ApplicationServices_Core_Application_Idle) event.